# Dynamic function name definition in Julia.. possible?

Tags: dataframe, julia, metaprogramming

I have a DataFrame structured as `parName|region|year`, and access function as `getData(parName,reg,year)` ( I use access function because I implement my own query logic).

Would it be possible, based on `unique(df[:parName])`, to dynamically create a set of functions like `par1(region,year)` "pointing to"  `getData("par1",region,year)` ?

If so, using which approach?

This is a bit the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016768/julia-invoke-a-function-by-a-given-string) question.. there it is explained how to dynamically call a function, while I wander if it possible to dynamically declare/define one..

**EDIT:**

I am using this approach in order to get the cleanest and most compact syntax possible in writing multi-dimensional equations.
I managed (thanks to the @Liso answer) to implement it as:

```
for par in unique(dropna(df[:parName]))
   @eval ($(Symbol("$(par)_"))) =   (r,d1,d2="",y=-1,op=sum) -> gd($par,r,d1,d2,y,op)
   @eval ($(Symbol("$(par)!"))) =   (v,r,d1,d2="",y=-1) -> sd(v,$par,r,d1,d2,y)
end
```

i.e., I am using the convention that `par!()` is a setData-type and `par_()` is a getData-type equation.
[When I'll be able to complete the macro that transforms `f(dim1,dim2) = value` into `f(value,dim1,dim2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546440/julia-macro-for-transforming-fdim1-dim2-value-into-fvalue-dim1-dim2) I will be able to write my model using a LaTeX-like (and AMPL-like) syntax that is very clear:

```
@meq  price!(tp in secProducts, r in fr2) = sum(price_(r,pp,"",y2)*a_(r,pp,tp,y2) for pp in priProducts) + margin_(r,tp,"",y2)
```

Comment: Why would you even do this though? In general it is highly discouraged to use unique 'ordered' identifiers for things that should otherwise belong in an array. At most, if you really want functions that take two arguments only, maybe you'd like to look at closure-generating functions and "currying" (i.e. create something you'd call like: `get("par1")(region, year)`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am just beginner trying to understand Julia, so I am not sure if it is good idea or not!

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#Code-Generation-1 .

I was able to adapt that example to this :

```
julia> for i in 4:6
    @eval ($(Symbol("func$i")))(a) = a^$i
end

julia> func4(2), func5(2), func6(2)
(16, 32, 64)
```

Maybe it could help you to play and learn :)

Comment: How do you add type signature into this? Thanks.

Comment: As you would do in regular functions. E.g.  `@eval ($(Symbol("func$i")))(a::Int) = a^$i`.
You could also iterate over multiple types if needed.