# Julia macro for transforming `f(dim1,dim2,..) = value` into `f(value,dim1,dim2,..)`

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

I am trying to write a Julia macro that transforms this:

```
[par1!( par2(d1,d2)+par3(d1,d2)   ,d1,d2,dfix3) for d1 in DIM1, d2 in DIM2]
```

(not very inspiring) into something much more readable, like this:

```
@meq par1!(d1 in DIM1, d2 in DIM2, dfix3) =  par2(d1,d2)+par3(d1,d2)
```

where `par1!()` is a function to set some multi-dimensional data and `par2()` is a getData()-type of function.

I am trying to implement it using a macro, but as I am on my first experience with julia marcro, I'm not sure how to "assemble" the final expression from the various pieces..
Here is what I done so far:

```
macro meq(eq)
   # dump(eq)
    lhs_par               = eq.args[1].args[1]
    rhs                   = eq.args[2]
    lhs_dims              = eq.args[1].args[2:end]
    loop_counters         = [d.args[2] for d in lhs_dims if typeof(d) == Expr]
    loop_sets             = [d.args[3] for d in lhs_dims if typeof(d) == Expr]
    loop_wholeElements    = [d for d in lhs_dims if typeof(d) == Expr]
    lhs_dims_placeholders = []
    for d in lhs_dims
        if typeof(d) == Expr
            push!(lhs_dims_placeholders,d.args[2])
        else
            push!(lhs_dims_placeholders,d)
        end
    end
    outExp =  quote
      [$(lhs_par)($(rhs),$(lhs_dims_placeholders ...)) for  $(loop_wholeElements ...) ]
    end
    #show(outExp)
    return outExp
end
```

However the above macro doesn't compile and returns a syntax error (“invalid iteration specification”) due to the `for $(loop_wholeElements)` part… indeed I don’t know how to treat the expressions in lhs_dims_placeholders and loop_wholeElements in order to “assemble” the expanded expression…

**EDIT:**

The example posted, with `d1`, `d2` and `dfix3`, is only a specific case, but the macro should be able to handle whichever dimensions are looped for..
I think the macro up there does that, but I don't know how to build the final expression.. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manually doing those hard-coded `args` matching stuff, we could use [MacroTools.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/MacroTools.jl) as a handy tool for template matching:

```
julia> using MacroTools

julia> macro meq(ex)
           @capture(ex, f_(d1_ in dim1_, d2_ in dim2_, dfix3_) = body__)
           ret = :([$f($(body[]), $d1, $d2, $dfix3) for $d1 in $dim1, $d2 in $dim2])
       end
@meq (macro with 1 method)

julia> prettify(@macroexpand @meq par1!(d1 in DIM1, d2 in DIM2, dfix3) =  par2(d1,d2)+par3(d1,d2))
:([(Main.par1!)((Main.par2)(lobster, redpanda) + (Main.par3)(lobster, redpanda), lobster, redpanda, Main.dfix3) for lobster = Main.DIM1, redpanda = Main.DIM2])
```

---

## UPDATE:

The desired final expression is a `comprehension`, it seems that for some reason Julia couldn't figure out `for expr`(where `$expr #=> XXX in XXX`) is a comprehension. The workaround is directly using [its lowered form](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/ast/#Bracketed-forms-1):

```
julia> using MacroTools

julia> par1(a, b, c, d) = a + b + c + d
par1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> par2(a, b) = a + b
par2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> macro meq(ex)
           @capture(ex, par_(dims__) = rhs_)
           loopElements = []
           dimsPlaceholders = []
           for d in dims
               @capture(d, di_ in DIMi_) || (push!(dimsPlaceholders, d); continue)
               # push!(loopElements, x) 
               push!(loopElements, :($di = $DIMi))
               push!(dimsPlaceholders, di)
           end
           ret = Expr(:comprehension, :($par($(rhs),$(dimsPlaceholders...))), loopElements...)
       end
@meq (macro with 1 method)

julia> prettify(@macroexpand @meq par1!(d1 in DIM1, d2 in DIM2, dfix3) =  par2(d1,d2)+par3(d1,d2))
:($(Expr(:comprehension, :((Main.par1!)(begin 
            (Main.par2)(bee, wildebeest) + (Main.par3)(bee, wildebeest)
        end, bee, wildebeest, Main.dfix3)), :(bee = Main.DIM1), :(wildebeest = Main.DIM2))))

julia> @meq par1(m in 1:2, n in 4:5, 3) =  par2(m,n) + par2(m,n)
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 18  21
 21  24
```

Note that, the variable scope of `d1,d2` in generated expression will be  wrong if we use `push!(loopElements, x)` rather than `push!(loopElements, :($di = $DIMi))`. Let's wait for someone knowledgeable to give a thorough explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will give it a try to MacroTool.jl if I really can't get the composition of the final expression in the macro I wrote

Comment: @Antonello your macro should work at the first glance, but for some reason that I can't explain, it doesn't work(see my edit above).

Comment: Thank you.. I was thinking the same, that the problem is because of being a comprehension.. I don't have access to a pc now, tomorrow I'll try.. otherwise I can always build a "code string" piece by piece and then use parse() on it to generate an expression..

Comment: @Antonello I don't think it's a good idea to use `string constructing + parse` kinda methods in Julia because we have full control of ASTs(thx to Jeff) and there must be a proper way for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to rely on an external package for this, the solution I provided on the Julia discourse should also work

```
return :([$(Expr(:generator,:($(Expr(:call,lhs_par,rhs,lhs_dims_placeholders...))),loop_wholeElements...))])
```

The key is to use the :generator constructor to make the loop expression

Also, rhs can be replaced with rhs.args[n] in order to eliminate the quote block and insert the expression directly.

This then produces the exact expression:

```
:([(par1!(par2(d1, d2) + par3(d1, d2), d1, d2, dfix3) for d1 in DIM1, d2 in DIM2)])
```

EDIT:

Alright, so I went ahead and tested this:

```
return Expr(:comprehension,Expr(:generator,Expr(:call,lhs_par,rhs.args[2],lhs_dims_placeholders...),loop_wholeElements...))
```

end

Then computing the result like this

```
meq(:(par1!(d1 = 1:2, d2 = 1:2, 3) =  par2(d1,d2)+par3(d1,d2))) |> eval
```

Comment: Just to mention that directly using the `Expr` `x in X`s in `loop_wholeElements` will cause a scope issue, we need to change `x in X` to `x = X` to fix this, take a look at the example in my updated post.

Comment: Thank you. (a) There is a problem with using the generator expression, in the comprehension being surrounded by an extra parenthesis (`[(expr)]` instead of `[expr]`); (b) I need to keep `rhs`, as if I replace with `rhs.args[2]` and the rhs contains other comprehensions, their loops parts are transformed from `for a in A, b in B` to `for a = A, b = B`. Is this a bug in Julia ?

Comment: @Antonello I'm not sure whether this is a bug or not. I've posted the MWE on [discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/help-in-making-multi-dimensional-equations-a-bit-sexier/6217/10).

Comment: Yes, I see now my original solution has an extra parenthesis in it.

Here is the final corrected version, this should give you exactly what you need:


    `return Expr(:comprehension,Expr(:generator,Expr(:call,lhs_par,rhs.args[2],lhs_dims_placeholders),loop_wholeElements...))`

Although, you need to be careful about using `rhs.args[2]` if you are not entering your command from the REPL, in that case you need to replace `[2]` with `[1]`.

It returns

    `:([par1!(par2(d1, d2) + par3(d1, d2), Any[:d1, :d2, :dfix3]) for d1 in DIM1, d2 in DIM2])`