# How to convert string into variable name from dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary like this

```
dictionary = {"1":"abc_123","2":"def_456" "3":"ghi_789"}
```

so I want to convert `"abc_123"` as a `abc_123` because I have a function call `abc_123`, can anyone help me please.

Comment: Seems like XY problem... What are you actually intending to do?

Comment: you can keep function's name (without  `()`)  instead of string  - `dictionary =  {"1": abc_123}` and late you can call using `()` - `dictionary["1"]()`. But you have to define function before you use its name in dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

```
# You have two functions.
>>> abc = lambda x: x**2
>>> xyz = lambda x: x**3
>>> type(abc), type(xyz)
(<class 'function'>, <class 'function'>)

# You have a key-value map of the names of the functions.
>>> d = {'1':'abc', '2':'xyz'}
>>> type(d['1'])
<class 'str'>

# Convert them into a key-value map of the index and the actual function.
>>> func_d = {k:eval(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> func_d[1]
```

See also:

- [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)
- [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)
- https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: If the variable is in the current module [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) is a better solution that `eval`

Answer (score 0):

You can [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) functions from their respective package by name, and then call them:

```
>>> import operator
>>> getattr(operator, "add")
<built-in function add>
>>> getattr(operator, "add")(1, 3)
4
```

So depending where your functions (e.g. `abc_123`) are stored, that may help you. But consider storing functions themselves in your dictionary, instead of their names…

I also would suggest you read up on [Python functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) in more detail.